# Como passar criptografia do C# pro PHP

Tags: php, c#, criptografia

Galera eu tenho que passar informação numérica de uma aplicação C# pra uma função em php de forma a ter um minimo de segurança.
Tenho que passar os pontos da minha aplicação (jogo) pro banco e quero, pra evitar que algum usuário mal intencionado altere sua pontuação, adicionar a função base64 pra mandar ela de um código pro outro.
 Preciso também que haja um tipo de chave string que só a aplicação e a função tenham pra assegurar que ninguém poderá, pela URL alterar seus dados maliciosamente e não sei como fazer isso, nem em C# e nem em PHP, como eu faço?
Conheço muito pouco somente de php e meu colega de trabalho de C#, no php,só sei ir até aqui:

```
<?php

$id_jogador= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id_jogador']);
$pontos =mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pontos']);

$pontos = base64_decode($pontos);

echo $pontos;

?>
```

Como eu ponho a partir daqui, ou nesse meio, uma chave string que tenha na aplicação C# do meu amigo que possa assegurar a perfeita comunicação segura dos códigos.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` é uma função obsoleta e removida do php7, não é um bom começo.

Comment: O jogo não pode se comunicar direto com o banco de dados? Precisa realmente passar por um script PHP pra salvar no banco?

Comment: Você pode usar [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) que é uma biblioteca que vai achar tanto no PHP quando no C# facilmente, você pode usar uma chave que só a aplicação PHP e C# conheçam e trafeguar esses dados e só abrir nos destinos.

Comment: Se um dado é recebido do cliente, você não pode confiar 100% nele não importa o que faça. Mas assumindo que sua aplicação possua uma chave secreta (e que o usuário não tenha root do seu aparelho - podendo ver essa chave) compartilhada com seu servidor, o que você precisa fazer é **assinar** os dados enviados e anexar a assinatura à requisição. No servidor, você verifica a assinatura, rejeitando a requisição se a assinatura não for válida. Lembre-se de incluir o id do jogador na assinatura, senão um jogador poderá alterar a pontuação de outro!

Comment: Nota: você pode usar criptografia assimétrica (RSA, ECDSA) para fazer essa assinatura digital - e no caso, a sugestão do @SK15 de usar OpenSSL é uma boa, não sei se existem melhores - mas também pode optar por usar criptografia simétrica. Nesse caso, haveria um único valor secreto compartilhado entre o servidor e o aplicativo, e a modalidade de assinatura que você usaria é chamada de MAC. Procure por HMAC, certamente existem funções tanto no PHP quanto no C# que fazem isso.